# Extensions to Minimal Gauged UBLM Model

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

Recently I have been reading a bit about BSM physics and came across the minimal gauged $U(1)_{B - L}$ model, where the gauge group of the Standard Model is extended to a larger product with another $U(1)$.

I was wondering if any experts could tell me how intensively the next to minimal case has been studied and the main extensions to the minimal model which have been studied in the literature (if any).

Edit: I've looked a bit more into this in the meantime, and the answer is very intensively, if anyone is interested.  That includes embedding the gauge group into a larger grand unified theory and also includes supersymmetry.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: BSM stands for Beyond the Standard Model and the UBLM in the title is meant to denote $U(1)_{B - L}$.